# Why won't my breakpoints get hit in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying the get the Visual Studio Code debugger working in my angular/typescript application but it's not working.

Here's what I have:

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug node",
      "port": 9229,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}\\.dist",
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/api/.dist",
      "type": "node"
    }
  ]
}
```

scripts/local-entry-point.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
echo "STARTING local-entry-point.sh"
FOLDER=/tmp/.dist
if [ ! -d "$FOLDER" ]; then
    mkdir /tmp/.dist
fi
false | cp -ir ${FOLDER}  /usr/src/api/ 2>/dev/null

rm -rf ${FOLDER}

cd scripts
npm run watch
```

scripts/package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@effect-ts/core": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "nodemon --watch '/usr/src/api/.dist/**/*' -e ts,json,js -x npm run debug",
    "debug": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 /usr/src/api/.dist/start.js"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
...
        ports:
            - 4002:8800
            - 9229:9229
...
```

I put breakpoints in both my Typescript and the compiled Javascript in the .dist folder (on the corresponding line):

[image]

[image]

I start my application (`npm run docker`), start the debugger in vscode, go through the steps to run the code, but the breakpoints don't get hit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You put a breakpoint inside `submitFunction`.  Did you ever actually call the `submitFunction` function anywhere?  (Did execution ever reach that line of code?)  Just setting a breakpoint doesn't break the program unless execution **reaches the breakpoint**.  Doesn't matter if we reached the point where you assign `submitFunction` a value (where you define the function).  The function actually has to get called somehow to hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Yes it does run submitFunction as my console logs print out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using Typescript. AFAIK VSCode debugger needs a sourcemap to put breakpoints on ts projects. I think this doc might help https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging

Comment: Thanks Boros, I will read that article and see what I can make of it.

Comment: I got around to trying the link. It didn't work. My breakpoint still isn't hit.